# The vector fields $F(x,y)=(py,-px)$ and $G(x,y)=(qy,-qx)$ are conjugated iff $|p|=|q|$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-fields, matrix-exponential

Consider the vector fields in $\Bbb{R}^2$:

$$F(x,y)=(py,-px),\quad G(x,y)=(qy,-qx) $$

I want to prove  that these vector fields are conjugated $\iff |p|=|q|$

By definition, $F$  and $G$ are conjugate if exists a diffeomorphism $H$ such that

$$H\,\circ F_t = G_t \,\circ H,   $$

where $F_t$ and $G_t$ are the trajectories of $F$ and $G$. Note that

$$F(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & p \\ -p & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix},\quad G(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}0 & q \\ -q & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} $$

So, the trajectories are given by the exponential of these matrix:

$$F_t(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos pt & \sin pt \\ -\sin pt & \cos pt\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix},\quad G_t(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}\cos qt & \sin qt \\ -\sin qt & \cos qt\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix} $$

My first attempt is work with linear $H$, that is, $H(x,y)=C\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y\end{bmatrix}$ for some matrix $C$. So, I need to work with

$$C e^{At}=e^{Bt}C, $$

where $A$ and $B$ are the matrix in the definition of $F$ and $G$ respectively.

What can I do?